# JSON Data - Validate Properties in PHP

Tags: php, json, schema

I'm trying to validate a simple schema against large JSON data. I only need to find if the properties I'm using in my PHP code are present in the JSON data. I've looked at several libraries but they seem overkill since they even validate the data type and I only need the presence of properties.

For example:
PHP variables I use: `name, age, gender`
JSON Data:

```
{
  "Location": "10.2.00",
  "Name": "Foo",
  "Age": "30",
  "Race": "NA",
  "Gender": "Male"
}
```

So there could be extra data in JSON.

**How can I check for the presence of JSON variables in my PHP code or another JSON schema?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to verify that the keys from your simple schema are present, you can use [`array_diff_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php).

Define your simple schema (keep in mind that the keys are case sensitive.)

```
$simple_schema = ['Name', 'Age', 'Gender'];
```

Decode your large JSON data (be sure to use the second argument of `json_decode` to get an array for comparison.)

```
$json = json_decode($large_json_data, true);
```

Then get the difference using [`array_diff_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php).

```
$missing_keys = array_diff_key(array_flip($simple_schema), $json);
```

The `array_flip` converts the values of your simple schema to keys for the comparison.

if `$missing_keys` is empty, then all the keys in your schema were present in the large JSON data.

Comment: @Don't Panic this is a gorgeous solution. The only down-side I see is the case sensitivity. Anyway to make insensitive?

Comment: It's possible to do it case-insensitively, but I don't think it would be possible with array_diff_key. You'd probably need to loop and convert both keys to a common case. If you knew that all the keys in the large data would be in a certain case, you could convert your simple schema keys to that case beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

So with the addition of the case-insensitivity:

```
$props = array('name', 'age', 'gender');
$array = array_map('strtolower', array_keys(json_decode($json, true)));

if(empty(array_diff($props, $array))) {
    echo "All properties exist";
}
```

- Use an array of lowercase property names
- Get the keys from the JSON and map to `strtolower()`
- Check if the difference is `empty()` meaning all properties exist